# Different source and destination port on azure vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I need to configure incoming https traffic(443) onto port 8443 (tomcat).

I have following Inbound security rules:

[image]

However, open port check for port 443 from http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ fails.

I have verified that tomcat is running on port 8443. What could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Classic Virtual Machine. In Resource Manager mode you need to create load balancer and create NAT Rules.

Deploy a sample load balancer from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/101-loadbalancer-with-nat-rule/

You might get the idea from it.